# Is SQLite Manager refreshing itself properly?

Tags: sqlitemanager

I added new rows to my database through SQLiteManager but I cannot see those values in my tableview. My old values are seen. More interestingly, I deleted my database file but I can see my old values again in my tableview. When I created new database with new name, it sees that. How can I make it perceive new values?

Comment: I second that. No accepts, no more answers.

Comment: I learned lot from your answers but I think I do not know how to pick answer.. Sorry for that and I appreciate your efforts much

Comment: I see you found the way! *thumbs up*, the people who answered you in the past will appreciate it.

Comment: I have done it ;) I did not recognize before.. Did you read above question? I think it is really problematic :)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer as there are at least two SQLite Managers.
[SQLiteManager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitemanager/) (standalone) and [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/5817) the Firefox Plugin.

If you haven't tried the Firefox Plugin yet I'd strongly recommend doing so. I'm very happy with it and have never touched another SQLite Browser since.

Comment: I am using SQLiteManager -the Firefox Plugin. I can't see my values on my tableview after I added them database

Comment: Hm. That's strange. It's working fine on SQLite 3.6.16.1 / Gecko 1.9.2.3 and SQLite Manager 0.5.12. You might try http://superuser.com/ as this seems not to be a programming related question.